# Upgrading issue in nopcommerce3.0 on the sql database

Tags: nopcommerce

I have upgrading issue in nopcommerce3.0 my current version in 2.3

for example:

Suppose I have Customer table(nopcommerce version 2.3) which have around 8044 rows then I  had upgrade script step by step until the version 3.0 then after I checked `Customer` table there only 5000 rows that means upgrade script deleted 3044 rows in `Customer` table what is the reason?

would you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your backup of the database and see if they were old Guest or search engine records.

Comment: Sorry @AndyMcKenna  i did not get your query could you please explain what you think

Comment: You should load your backup of the database and then do a join between the two Customer tables to see what records were deleted.  Once you have that list, you can look at a few columns to determine what they were.  You can also join on Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping.  You can check to see if they were all Guest accounts.  If your Delete Guest task doesn't usually run but did after the upgrade, it might have wiped out a bunch of unneeded records.  You won't know for sure until you compare the databases, though.